# How can I achieve a ribbed pipe/tube effect in Photoshop or Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm looking to create a tube with an effect like the following - the cylindrical segments which come together to make a pipe. I was wondering how this might be achieved; You could layer ellipsis with lighting effects over each other, but does anyone know of an alternative method to achieve?

Yes, it looks something like a hoover pipe.

[image: Hoover pipe]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Make the basic appearance of the tube with Illustrator's pattern feature](http://wedesignstudios.com/2012/07/how-to-make-a-telephone-cord-in-illustrator/).

Then you can add the fancy pancy stuff (like glows, bevels and shadows) in Photoshop.